# Loading Fluentui 9.19.1 React components' style on Microsoft SharePoint WebPart

Tags: typescript, microsoft-teams, spfx, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm currently developing a Microsoft WebPart.
I'm using "yo @microsoft/sharepoint" to generate the project with React framework and I'd like to use the new "@fluentui/react-components" to design the WebPart.

But, when I deploy the application, the components appear without any style...

[On App view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGnr9.png)

Extract from the code I use (.tsx file)

```
import { LargeTitle, Divider, Button } from '@fluentui/react-components';
import { DocumentRegular } from '@fluentui/react-icons'

<LargeTitle>Title:</LargeTitle>
<Button appearance="primary" icon={<DocumentRegular />}>
            Primary
</Button>
<Divider />
```

Expected Result : [Expected Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuqoH.png)

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

I have already tried:
-to change browser
-to clear the cache
-to uninstall the package and then reinstall it
-to install the package with npm install @fluentui/react-components or yarn add @fluentui/react-components.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please try with this-
 <Button icon={<DocumentRegular />} content="Primary" iconPosition="before" primary />

Comment: also refer the-https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.63.1/components/button/definition?showCode=true&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#usage-content-and-icon

Comment: The SPFX build process externalises a bunch of imports. This means your dev copy will not be used. You can tweak this in the gulp file by extending the webpack config and removing the externals that you want to be internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found a way to load my FluentUI's style on my WebPart.
First, I have to include my components in a Fluent Provider and add a theme :

```
import {
  FluentProvider,
  teamsLightTheme,
  Button
} from '@fluentui/react-components';

...

    <FluentProvider theme={teamsLightTheme}>
       <Button appearance=primary>
          Button
       </Button>
    </FluentProvider>
```

Comment: Many thanks for (accidentally) providing a mini tutorial on implementing FluentUI 9! It helped me to make it work! 
Is there any more information about the available themes? How does it work to get the current SharePoint theme? And how to switch based on context (ie. Teams or SharePoint(?